# uncaught reference error: FileTransfer not defined at cordova.js(3.0.0)

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3

I am bulding a simple cross platform app using cordova 3.0.0. The installation went fine. But I cannot seem to get the file transfer to work. I keep getting this error. 
 `processMessage failed: Error: ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1035`

I have installed all the plugins properly and also calling device ready as such:

```
function onLoad(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
function uploadFileForCapture(mediaFile) {
        var ftforcapture = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;
            alert(path + name);
        ftforcapture.upload(path,
            "http:/some.server.com/upload.php",
            function(result) {
                alert('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                alert(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });
    }
```

Can some one please help!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error as well. For me the file transfer plugin was never successfully installed. It was not in the android platform folder with the other plugins that I was using. I was installing with the cli client. I created a fresh project and noticed that when I ran this cordova plugin add command that I received this error.

[TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings]

I tried a clean install on a virtual machine expecting it to be something in my setup but it still didn't work. Before I could file a bug report on it, Cordova 3.1.0 was released. I created my project over and this time the file transfer plugin was successfully installed.